# How do i get all the Application commands on a discord bot, Including subcommands?

Tags: python, nextcord

So, i have a discord bot with over 120 slash commands. the way my slash commands are formatted are like this:

```
@client.slash_command(name="fun")
async def fun(interaction: Interaction):
    pass

@fun.subcommand(name="command")
async def funcommand(interaction: Interaction):
    #command code
```

I Have several of these sub command starters. I am using NEXTCORD, PYTHON. My question is: how can i get all of these subcommands, as actual command objects that includes name and description(anything else is not required but will be good if provided.)

I tried using the get_all_commands(). i was expecting it to work, but it only showed the nextcord built in help command, since by bot does not have any prefix commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every SlashApplicationCommand have `children` attribute.

You can get full list of commands like in this example:

```
commands = []

def add_command(command: nextcord.SlashApplicationCommand | nextcord.SlashApplicationSubcommand, parent_name=''):
    commands.append(
        {"name": parent_name + command.name, "help": command.description, "brief": command.description})

def explore_command(command: nextcord.SlashApplicationCommand | nextcord.SlashApplicationSubcommand, parent_name=""):
    if not command.children:
        add_command(command, parent_name)
    else:
        for child in command.children.values():
            explore_command(child, parent_name + command.name + " ")

for slash_command in self.client.get_all_application_commands():
    explore_command(slash_command)
```